# ST_GeomFromText() Cannot be used with DB::raw?

Tags: mysql, laravel, geometry

I'm trying to create an UpdateOrCreate method that registers the geometry as binary

By query running
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) from mma_embargos;

INSERT INTO mma_embargos (geometry)
VALUES (
ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON ((-55.18473 -6.884111, -55.183144 -6.889768,...'
));

Works correctly saving as
0x00000000103000000010000000D000000884B8....

In laravel I'm trying to use DB::raw to pass the ST_GeomFromText() function

```php
public static function updateOrCreate(
    string  $numTad,
    string  $document,
    int     $numProcess,
    array   $data,
    ?string $geometry
): IbamaMmaEmbargos
{
    return DB::transaction(function () use ($numTad, $document, $numProcess, $data, $geometry) {
        $embargo = MmaEmbargos::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'num_tad' => $numTad,
                'document' => $document,
                'num_processo' => $numProcess,
            ],
            $data,
        );

        if (isset($geometry)){
            $embargo->update(
                [
                    'geometry' => DB::raw("ST_GeomFromText('$geometry')")
                ]
            );
        }
        return $embargo;
    });
}
```

With the same polygon, the error message is always returning "SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field (SQL: update `mma_embargos` set `geometry` = { }, `mma_embargos`.`updated_at` = 2023-12-11 12:49:37 where `id` = 1)",

Comment: Perhaps your $geometry variable is not correctly populated.

Comment: @Shadow This works when passed directly as
 ` DB::statement("
            UPDATE mma_embargos
            SET geometry_wkt = ST_GeomFromText(?)
            WHERE id = ?
        ", [$geometry, $embargo->id]);`

And through the model, DB::raw(ST_GeomFromText($geometry))) returns null

Comment: Passing values through parameters is not the same as passing a value through string interpolation. Check if something goes wrong there.

Comment: do `dd($geometry)` to double check that it has the value you expect

Comment: Apparently this is correctl @apokryfos

dd in geometry, it shows me a string like "POLYGON ((-55.18473 -6.884111, -55.183144 -6.889768,...


Already with DB:raw
returns a Query Expression "ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((-55.18473 -6.884111, -55.183144 -6.889768, -55.182109 -6.889975, -55.180798 ...

But when executed, it returns a null geometry.
`mma_embargos set geometry = {}`.

Comment: I will keep the geometry update isolated, making the query via DB::statement.
It must be something that the ORM does not support natively and I will study some spatial library

@Shadow